# How can I color every alternate table row in gt table in R

Tags: r, tidyverse, gt

I want every other row in my gt table to be `"grey"`.
Is anyone aware of an already existing function

```r
library(palmerpenguins)
library(gt)

penguins %>%
  dplyr::select(1:3) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:10) %>% 
  gt()
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We could use `opt_stylize`:
The easiest way to style a gt table is to apply a pre-installed theme via opt_stylize().

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(gt)

penguins |>
  dplyr::select(1:3) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:10) %>% 
  gt()|>
  opt_stylize(style = 1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tab_style`:

```r
penguins %>%
  dplyr::select(1:3) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:10) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  tab_style(style = cell_fill(color = "grey"),
            locations = cells_body(rows = seq(1, 10, 2)))
```

Or with `gtExtras::gt_highlight_rows`:

```r
penguins %>%
  dplyr::select(1:3) %>%
  dplyr::slice(1:10) %>% 
  gt() %>% 
  gtExtras::gt_highlight_rows(rows = seq(1, 10, 2), fill = "grey", font_weight = NULL)
```